# When will I ever need to use @WebServiceRef?

Tags: java, jax-ws

From the client side, if I want to access a web service, I would simply generate a proxy for it using `wsimport`. That is my web service reference.

Where then does the annotation [@WebServiceRef](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/xml/ws/WebServiceRef.html) come into play? Is it meant to be used at the server side only, to obtain injected references to web services hosted in the same environment?

Comment: In java SE clients it is not needed as it seems: `//@WebServiceRef(wsdlLocation="http://localhost:8080/JaxWsExample/NewWebServiceService?wsdl")
 private static NewWebServiceService service = new NewWebServiceService();` and it works

Comment: However in servlet based clients, it is mandaory (and no need to instantiate the service)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Not necessarily, but it really is something that depends on the server implementation. e.g. To access a remote service, it requires to have access to generated client and optionally to the WSDL documents and schemes files (by convention
should be in `WEB-INF/wsdl`), so that

```
public class HelloServlet extends HttpServlet {

    @WebServiceRef(HelloMessengerService.class) // class with @WebServiceClient
    private HelloMessenger port; // the SEI

    ...
}
```

The `HelloMessengerService` class is the stub and has the `@WebServiceClient` annotation which has a
`wsdlLocation` attribute (points to local o remote WSDL document).

But you can have something like that

```
@WebServiceRef(wsdlLocation = "META-INF/wsdl/AnyService/Any.wsdl")
private HelloMessengerService service;
```

or

```
@WebServiceRef
public HelloMessengerService service;
```

If you use a handler chain to alter incoming and outgoing SOAP messages:

```
@WebServiceRef(HelloMessengerService.class)
@HandlerChain(file="handler-chain.xml")
private HelloMessenger port;
```

The use of the `@WebServiceRef` annotation must be applied to JAX-WS-managed clients, like a Servlet, EJB, or another Web service.

Comment: The differences between Java EE components and "standard" Java classes are that Java EE components are assembled into a Java EE application, they are verified to be well formed and in compliance with the Java EE specification, and they are deployed to production, _where they are run and managed by the Java EE server_. [more...](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnaay.html#bnabb)

Answer (score 5):

Just to add to Paul Vargas' answer, the `@WebServiceRef` annotation is a tool to complete the evolution of the Java EE platform to a wholly managed environment. Think about it this way:

Almost every component within the Java EE stack is injectable by some means, EJBs, JSF managed beans, CDI beans, `@Resources` etc. Why not be able to inject a webservice reference? With the ability to inject a webservice reference using this annotation, the following are ready injection targets:

- EJBs
- Servlets (under Servlet 3.0)
- JSF Managed Beans
- CDI Beans
- MDBs