# JSF Connection to EJB SOAP Web Service

Tags: jsf, service, ejb, jax-ws

I am trying to connect the managed bean of the JSF application to the EJB deployed as the SOAP web service. I have an EJB which implements SEI and methods exposed. The ejb-jar is deployed separately and its wsdl can be accessed as soon as it is deployed - nothing special.

Then I have a JSF app. I want its managed bean to communicate with this service I have written. The JSF app is deployed on the same glassfish machine. But the condition is necessary that it communicates with the EJB using SOAP web service.

How can I inject web service into the JSF project? Or do I need to generate classes for the web service using wsimport? Or which way is the most common for the standalone web application to access a separate SOAP web service?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using the `@WebServiceRef` annotation:

```
@WebServiceRef(wsdlLocation = "http://localhost/HelloWS/hello.wsdl")
private HelloMessengerService service;
```

See more:

- [Sample Application using JAX-WS, JSF, EJB 3.0, and Java Persistence APIs on Glassfish.](https://weblogs.java.net/blog/caroljmcdonald/archive/2007/09/sample_applicat_2.html)
- [Using @WebserviceRef in the client application.](http://java.boot.by/ocewsd6-guide/ch06s02.html)
- [When will I ever need to use @WebServiceRef?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15661262/when-will-i-ever-need-to-use-webserviceref)